# Chromediver não abre no windows 7

Tags: google-chrome

Estou com o seguinte problema:

Quando execute Cucumber em meu projeto retorna a seguinte mensagem e não carrega chromedriver:

> No such file or directory - powershell.exe "(Get-ItemProperty 'C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe').VersionInfo.ProductVersion" (Errno::ENOENT)

Já fui nas configurações e retireia barra que está em duplicidade, já reconfigurei o Path algumas vezes e nada.

Comment: tive este mesmo problema porém com o `Selenium` e a causa era a divergência de versões entre o `chromedriver` e a versão do `Chrome` instalado na máquina que estava rodando a aplicação. Já verificou as versões do `chromedriver` com o `Chrome` ?

Comment: Olá Lao, o que seria Cucumber? Seria isso https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/browser-automation/ ? E qual esta usando? Pode fornecer detalhes?